# Проект запускается в embedded tomcat, но не работает в полной версии tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, rest, spring-boot

Я написал небольшой проект используя SpringBoot с несколькими RESTful-сервисами, для изучения фреймворка и REST-технологии.
При запуске через spring-boot:run все корректно работает, доступно на http://localhost:8080/ и далее по ссылкам указанным через @RequestMapping в контроллере. К примеру, по http ://localhost:8080/restapp/test/{id} :

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "http ://localhost:8080/restapps-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/restapp/test/{id}",
        method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String getWelcome(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
    return "Welcome to jax-rs " + id;
}
```

При попытке деплоя в полный tomcat, проект запускается на http ://localhost:8080/project_version и открывает по умолчанию index.html файл (о чем я узнал случайно, т.к. этот файл переносил для начального тестирования), и далее к сервисам доступа нету, по всем адресам:

http ://localhost:8080/project_version/restapp/test/{id}

http ://localhost:8080/project_version/test/{id}

http ://localhost:8080/project_version/project_name/restapp/test/{id}

выдаёт 404.

Application.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
@RestController
public class Controller extends ApplicationConfig {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> s = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        s.add(Controller.class);
        return s;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "http ://localhost:8080/restapps-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/restapp/test/{id}",
            method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getWelcome(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
        return "Welcome to jax-rs " + id;
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfig - пустой класс, расширяющий Application.

Спасибо за любые советы/ответы.

Comment: В логе Tomcat просто показано множество моих запросов и 404 на каждый.

Comment: проверь есть ли вообще твоё приложение с джарниками внутри томката

Comment: @AdamSkywalker так, интересно, а можно ещё вопрос как заставить maven-war-plugin упаковать все мои классы в архив, а не только настройки и то что Maven импортировал?

Comment: не работал с ним. если не упаковал, возможно ему путь не передается откуда классы проекта брать.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker упаковал, но это ничего не изменило
Впрочем, завтра ещё попробую покопать в этом направлении, может я был близок к решению, но т.к. протупил в этом моменте ничего не выходило, спасибо.

Comment: Вы не создали корректно артефакт для деплоя. Кто так задает маппинг ссылок на апи value = "http ://localhost:8080/restapps-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/restapp/test/{id}" ??? это вообще что, т.е. вам нужно с локалки еще перейти по полному адресу с протоколом? Это ведь дичь сер, вот ваша ссылка /test/{id} на апи

Comment: Ещё момент - мне кажется что до запуска Application'a вообще не доходит, т.к.  после добавления строк `Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Application.class.getName());
        log.info("///////// Application started successfully, ////////");`
Ничего в лог не внеслось, помимо записей о деплое.

Comment: @GenCloud пардон, знаю, данная дичь появилась в ходе попыток возродить программу, вдруг хоть так зарботало бы...
Вот так выглядит в оригинале:

    `@RestController
    @RequestMapping(value = "/restapp")
    public class Controller extends ApplicationConfig {
    ...
    @RequestMapping(value = "/test/{id}",
                method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String getWelcome(@PathVariable(value = "id") String id) {
            return "Welcome to jax-rs " + id;
        }
    }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К вашему решению есть несколько замечаний:

1. Компоненты Spring Framework должны быть атомарными, а связи между ними - строго через IoC.
2. Конфигурации и компоненты - разные вещи. Даже между классами конфигураций не предполагается наследования (через @Import). А, уж, наследовать контроллер от конфига совсем не стоит.
3. Касательно деплоя в обычный Tomcat. Надо учитывать, что Tomcat - это контейнер сервлетов, а значит каждое приложение должно реализовывать стандарт сервлетов. В случае Spring Boot достаточно просто унаследовать Application от SpringBootServletInitializer и собрать WAR архив. После деплоя в Tomcat вы получите традиционное приложение с инициализированым контекстом Spring Framework. Подробности можно найти [в документации](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html)

Comment: Наследование от SpringBootServletInitializer решило проблему.